# What nutrient solution is best for hydroponic basil?

Tags: herbs, basil, hydroponic, nutrients

What hydroponic nutrient solution is best for growing basil?

I'd prefer to know what characteristics to look for rather than a particular brand or product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [PDF](http://pgohort.co.nz/resources/1/crop%20data/Basil%20data.pdf) gives a good breakdown

**ppm Mineral levels for specific CF ranges for Basil**

|  | CF10 | CF12 | CF18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NITROGEN | 33-100 | 40-120 | 60-180 |
| PHOSPHOROUS | 8-25 | 10-30 | 15-45 |
| POTASSIUM | 50-150 | 60-180 | 90-270 |
| SULPHUR | 13-40 | 16-48 | 24-72 |
| CALCIUM | 33-118 | 40-142 | 60-210 |
| MAGNESIUM | 8-25 | 10-30 | 15-45 |
| SODIUM | 3-35 | 3-35 | 3-35 |
| CHLORIDE | 3-35 | 3-35 | 3-35 |
| IRON | 0.7-3.6 | 0.8-3.6 | 1.2-5.0 |
| MANGANESE | 0.13-1.6 | 0.16-1.9 | 0.24-3.0 |
| BORON | 0.07-0.5 | 0.08-0.6 | 0.12-0.9 |
| ZINC | 0.03-1.0 | 0.04-1.0 | 0.06-1.0 |
| COPPER | 0.03-0.33 | 0.04-0.36 | 0.06-0.5 |
| pH RANGE | 6.0-6.5 | 6.0-6.5 | 6.0-6.5 |

Based on that you are looking for high Nitrogen, Potassium and Calcium.

Comment: What does CF stand for?

Comment: CF is the Conductivity Factor, The electrical conductivity of the nutrient solution which goes up and down with the concentration of the solution.

Comment: "Page not found"

Comment: Good thing I posted all the important bits here then...