# Guide for the nutrient requirements of hydroponic plants,

Tags: hydroponic, nutrients

I require the hydroponic nutrient requirements for:

- artichoke (vegetative)
- artichoke (flowering)
- cannabis (vegetative)
- cannabis (flowering)

I use Kratky buckets for my plants.

I see @dogmatic69 posted exactly what I needed for basil in [post 7258](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7258/what-nutrient-solution-is-best-for-hydroponic-basil).

Comment: Can you provide more details about what kind of hydroponics?  Without that your question may be closed as too broad

Comment: @kevinsky I added themethod used, not that it will really make a difference to the answer.  (btw do you know how to reopen an answer to this question?)

Comment: @niall-c I have copied the imprtant facts from the link to my answer.