# Optimal hydroponic nutrient solutions for different herbs

Tags: fertilizer, herbs, hydroponic, nutrients

I'm planning to grow different herbs hydroponically: basil, sage, mint and thyme.
I would like for the nutrient solutions for each herb to be the closest possible to the optimum.

For basil I found [this resource](http://www.e-gro.org/pdf/E303.pdf) elaborating on the target ppm per each nutrient, and also [this answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7258/what-nutrient-solution-is-best-for-hydroponic-basil) for sufficient ranges. However, I couldn't find similar tables for the other herbs.

I would be grateful if anyone could provide such tables of sage, mint and thyme (and optimally if there was a source which provides optimal nutrient solution for any herb and/or plant).